# How to make groovy accept vm arg -Xss

Tags: groovy, vmargs

I have ported some litle Java application to Groovy. The Java application needs to be started with the VM switches -server -Xss15500k to prevent a stackoverflow from happening. The question is how to pass these vm args on to groovy. I tried this here:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin
groovy -server -Xss15500k MyApp.groovy
```

and this here:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;%GROOVY_HOME%\bin
SET JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xss15500k
groovy MyApp.groovy
```

It both doesn't work and I get an OutOfmemoryError unlike the Java counterpart. Any hints how to get this done appreciated :-).

Thanks, Oliver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're getting an `OutOfMemoryError` then you probably want to increase the memory as well as the stack

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=-server -Xss15500k -Xmx1G
```

Comment: This did it. -Xm1G wasn't necessary for the Java version and I kept thinking that groovy simply doesn't pick up the vm args at all. Thanks a lot!